# object compose small number of source objects limit (32)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to compose some rather largish (~50-10GB) objects on cloud storage and the compose object limit seems arbitrarily low - only 32 items.  So I'm currently using 350MB chunks -- why is the limit so low?

I read somewhere that an iterative compose doesn't work - is that correct?  ie, if I wanted to compose 64 objects to two, then two to 1 - does that not work?

Answer (score 1):

One single request can only compose 32 components, but you can compose composed objects. The overall limit is 1024:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#_Compose

Comment: Okay, thanks, missed those details - the 32 at a time limit still seems arbitrarily low...